# sbt-launch.jar not recognizing scala 2.9.1 already installed

Tags: scala, installation, sbt, typesafe-stack

I've just installed the [Typesafe Stack](http://typesafe.com/stack) and am now trying to install SBT via the instructions on the [SBT github page](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Setup).

However, the SBT installer does not recognize that Scala is already installed, and tries to download a fresh version:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-120-65-227:~/bin$ sbt
Getting Scala 2.9.1 (for sbt)...
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.9.1/scala-compiler-2.9.1.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.9.1!scala-compiler.jar (2108ms)
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.9.1/scala-library-2.9.1.jar ...
^C
```

I'd like it to use the current version specified in $SCALA_HOME.  Anyone know how to get it to do that?

Current env settings:

```
$SCALA_HOME='/usr/local/typesafe-stack/bin/'
$PATH='...:/usr/local/typesafe-stack/bin:...'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using xsbt 0.11, you can specify the local scala using

```
scalaHome := Some(file("/path/to/scala"))
```

You will want to put this into the global settings in your home directory at

```
~/.sbt/global.sbt
```

If you are using sbt 0.7 then go [here](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/LocalScala)

Comment: Thanks Neil.  It doesn't quite work, but I found that config directive on the sbt wiki (https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Local-Scala).  It looks like that directive will cause sbt to use the specified Scala for building projects, but sbt will still download the copy of Scala it was compiled against to run itself, even if the version it was compiled against is installed.  Am I interpreting that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently run Windows 7 and XP on my machine. And I have not the "home" in windows. I have installed Scala 2.9 and SBT on that. But I have the same problem. The SBT can not recognize the scala.